# K8s pod oom kill with high file cache and file_dirty memory

Tags: kubernetes, caching, memory, cgroups

I'm observing oom kill of my pod in the deployment. Checking cgroup's memory.stat found high file cache memory of 2gb and file_dirty memory of 1.8gb. Other memory are in expected line but not sure about the reason for file_dirty memory reaching high, what could be the reason for high file_dirty and how to avoid it ? Improper configuration of log4j can be the reason ? Pl let know.

I can increase pod memory limit but not sure if file_dirty will have same issue then.